# How to remove 404 error page not found when installing a magento extension?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a magento extension for Check availability for a product in a online store.I have installed it, after updating the configurations of that extension in the System tab, it is showing 404 error page not found.Can anyone say y it is like that ?

Comment: Logout and login again and check it.If not working show your code

Answer (score 0):

Magento use `acl resources`, and ACL tree is loaded when the session is initialized! That's why when you install some module that could not find the page for that new module. So for see that new module page `you need to logout first then login again`! You will see that the **404** will be gone!